# USB Devices Lose Power / Stop Working after OS (XP SP 3) loads

Tags: windows-xp, usb, keyboard, mouse

After suffering a BSOD, I switched off my Dell Dimension.  When I turned it back on and it reached the XP login screen, both my USB mouse and keyboard lost power.  I turned it back on and hit F2 to get to setup to make sure "onboard USB devices" was set to "on."  Both USB devices work properly in Setup, but once I load XP (normally or in safe mode), the indicator lights die, and both USB devices cease working.  I haven't made any updates recently, and the devices are the same ones I've been using for years (so there are no new drivers involved).  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

General background:

Unless special care is taken  USB devices do not work before the OS is loaded and drivers are initialised. (Specifically the USB stack/drivers).

This means, -again unless special care is taken- that you can not use an USB based keyboard or mouse before the OS load. Which is not useful is you need to change something in the BIOS.

To counter this a modern BIOS contains rudimentary USB drivers which are enabled if you turn on *legacy USB support*.

Now on to your problem:

What is most likely happening is that you power on the computer. The basic BIOS USB routines give you some control, resulting in a working mouse, keyboard and basic USB-boot capability.

Then during the OS start-up XP takes over with its own drivers. At this point things go wrong.

The most likely reasons for this are:

1. Driver problems. (But you wrote you did not install any new drivers).
2. Disk problems. E.g. failure to read the files containing the USB drivers. This should show up in the event viewer.
3. Hardware problems which did not manifest themselves when USB was only used for the most basic tasks.

Try booting the computer without any USB devices at all. If it does not crash add them back one by one. If a single device keeps crashing your computer test it on another PC. It might just be broken somehow.. If the computer only boots with no USB devices at all then try booting it and logging in via a remote session (e.g. use RDP, VNC etc, depending on what was installed).

Lastly, if you do have access to a second computer, try a live CD. If it works with the OS on the live CD then you know the hardware is fine. (In other words, despite no new drivers you still have a software problem).